# Android 12 SplashActivity theme breaks CardView style

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-12

There is a custom `AlertDialog` in my app appearing in `SplashActivity` as follows:

[image: Original popup]

The XML layout of the `AlertDialog` is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <LinearLayout>
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

When I migrate my `SplashActivity` to new `SplashScreen` API in Android 12, I have to set its theme as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As a result, it breaks my custom `AlertView` as follows:

[image]

In conclusion, something breaks `app:cardBackgroundColor` attribute on `CardView` which is the root of my custom `AlertView`

If you look at the broken `AlertView` carefully, it seems there is a yellow layout over the `CardView` coming from nowhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, did you find the problem ?